# jQuery  - '.on' and ':first'

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use the `:first` and `:last` selectors with jQuery's on selector?

I want the first link in each list item to trigger the alert. However, at the moment, only the very first link triggers it.

The JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('ul').on("click", "li a:first", function(event) {
            alert("test");
        });
    }
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Trigger</a>
        <a href="#">Don't Trigger</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Trigger</a>
        <a href="#">Don't Trigger</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pjgalbraith/tuJnv/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `:first-child` instead

```
$('ul').on("click", "li a:first-child", function(event) {
    alert("test");
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/tuJnv/1/

As the doc says

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be
>   written as :lt(1).
>
> While this matches only a single element,
>   :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

`:first` will match only one element, first on selected set of elements. Where `:first-child` will find one(`the first child`) for each parent which is what you want.

Doc on [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

Comment: Thanks this works forgot about the first-child selector. I will accept this when I can.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `:first` to `:first-child`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready( function(){ 
        $('ul').on("click", "li a:first-child", function(event) { 
            alert("test"); 
        }); 
    } 
</script>
```

Location of code on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuJnv/3/.

Answer (score -1):

In can be done like this for example - http://jsfiddle.net/tuJnv/7/